# Component not loading on feature module router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to implement lazy loading for feature modules.How can I load components declared in feature module on `router-outlet` defined in feature module component?

I have one base module (`AppModule`) with component(`AppComponent`) having `router-outlet`.
There is another module `HomeModule` with its own `HomeComponent` having another `router-outlet`. `HomeModule` is being lazily loaded and defined in `AppRoutingModule`
(included in `AppModule`) as following :

```
{
    path:'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule)
}
```

`HomeModule` has its own routing module(`HomeRoutingModule`) and own router-outlet in `HomeComponent`. There are two components `NavigationComponent` and `IndexComponent` which declared in `HomeModule`.
`HomeRoutingModule` :

```
{
    path : '',component : HomeComponent,
    path : 'index',component : IndexComponent
}
```

`HomeComponent` is defined as following :

```
<navigation></navigation>
<router-oulet></router-oulet>
```

I am trying to load `IndexComponent` on 'home/index' with `NavigationComponent` from `HomeComponent` html as above.
Here is how I am routing to the url :

```
thi.router.navigate(['home/index'])
```

But somehow only `IndexComponent` is visible not `NavigationComponent`(`<navigation></navigation>`) whereas `IndexComponent` should be loaded with `router-outlet` of `HomeComponent` html with `NavigationComponent`

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the IndexComponent, you need to provide it as children to HomeComponent in the route .

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'index',
        component: IndexComponent
      },
}
```

Also, let me know if there are any console errors?

Comment: I am getting `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index'`